# Iterate over an array of object and change object value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to iterate over an array of objects that looks like this:

```
const arr = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "John",
  storeName: "Amazon",
  price: 100,
  isRecieved: false,
  deliveryDate: some date
}, ....]
```

I'm iterating over the array with product ID that I received from the user, finding the relevant item according to it's id and changing the key "isRecieved" from false to true.

This is my code:

```
const filterReceivedProduct = (list, id) => {
  const changeReceivedState = list.filter((item) => {
      return item.id === id ? **item[isRecieved]** = true : item;
  })
  return changeReceivedState
}
```

But when I'm trying to access the object using bracket notation it return the value (in this case 'false') and I can't change the value to true..

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Comment: `isRecieved` is not a variable. You should use dot notation:  `item.isRecieved`. The bracket notation would be `item["isRecieved"]`.

Comment: @NickParsons Yes also Angular and ngrx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `.filter()` here. The filter method is for *removing* elements from an array. What you want to do is [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each element/object to a new object, which has all the properties from the old object, containing an updated `isRecieved` property. To create a new object with all the properties of the old object, you can [*spread*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the properties and values from the old object into a new one (`{...item}`). You can then update the `isRecived` based on your whether the item id matched the id passed into your function:

```js
const arr = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "John",
  storeName: "Amazon",
  price: 100,
  isRecieved: false,
  deliveryDate: 'some date'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "Alex",
  storeName: "Apple",
  price: 200,
  isRecieved: false,
  deliveryDate: 'some date2'
}];

const filterReceivedProduct = (list, id) =>
  list.map(item => ({
    ...item,
    isRecieved: item.id === id // sets isRecieved to true or false based on the equalty comparison
  }));

const res = filterReceivedProduct(arr, 1);
console.log(res);
```

By creating a new object within the `.map()` callback, you're never mutating the original objects in your `arr`, treating everything as immutable.

Answer (score 2):

Here `filter` make no sense. Filter use to `filter` some array based on condition. If you just want to change some property of an object inside array then use `map` for this purpose.

See below example.

```js
const arr = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "John",
  storeName: "Amazon",
  price: 100,
  isRecieved: false,
  deliveryDate: 'some date'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "Doe",
  storeName: "Amazon",
  price: 100,
  isRecieved: false,
  deliveryDate: 'some date'
}];

filterReceivedProduct = (list, id) => {
  return list.map(item => {
    if(item.id === id) {
      item.isRecieved = true;
    }
    return item;
  });
}

console.log(filterReceivedProduct(arr, 1))
```

Comment: Use of `map` make no sense here.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Reason?

Comment: Thanks but item.isRecieved also returns the object value and again, I can't change the value itself and there is an error : Cannot assign to read only property 'isRecieved' of object '[object Object]'

Comment: filter use to filter out some of the array based on some condition.

Comment: @Shira See my answer below which uses filter which works the same way as map. As per the your question that what was needed.

Comment: @VivekJain i know but i am following what OP has already. OP might need filter best hence its being used in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to duplicate the array, and manipulate the current array, forEach can be the answer

```
list.forEach((item) => {
    item.isRecieved = item.id === id ? true: false;
});
```